# How can I conditionally render an attribute on HTML element in jspx

Tags: html, oracle-adf, scriptlet, jspx

Unfortunately I'm stuck using ADF/JSPX on this particular project.  How can I conditionally add an attribute to an element?

```
     <input id="i1" type="radio" name="address_radio" value="S" 
ng-model="addressType"/>
```

I want to conditionally render `checked="checked"` inside the element. Its quite easy to EL render a value, but in this case I need to actually script out the attribute name and value. The presence of the attribute is what actually sets it on the element. I believe checked="false" would actually also check the radio button. Anyways, without writing a custom tag library how can I easily accomplish this? Don't fail me once again jspx/adf. I imagine its quite simple and I simply don't know how. I saw scriptlets but I dont think you can use that in jspx. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself using HTML element on adf page, you should know, that you doing something very wrong there. You should use `<af:selectBooleanCheckbox>` instead.

However, if you pretty sure, you need it there, you have few solutions available:
1. Use some adf element to wrap html code and set conditional expression to render or not to render some code inside this wrapper.
2. You can output html with `<af:outputText escape="false" value="&gt;your html code>"/>`
3. Use javascript to alter html element attributes.

And once again, you should never have to deal with plain html in adf pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very honest answer. I come from jQuery/javascript front end background. They needed someone with strong html and css skills to render the designs that creative wants. Unfortunately they have no one with WebCenter Portal/ADF experience so we're using lots of custom stuff to get the correct look and feel. Accessibility is also a very high requirement and the ADF controls don't allow ARIA attributes as far as we can see. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you need someone who know how to drive this "car". Otherwise better to throw it away. ADF capable of doing almost anything you want, however you should have some knowledge on how to do it. Also it has ARIA support too.

Comment: Believe me I wish I could throw ADF and Oracle out the window but thry're using WebLogicPortal 10.3.6 so I believe we have to use ADF and jDeveloper 11.1.1.7. I've never been a fan of these drag and drop designers. It's more for a developer that cannot do front end correctly.